# Check for data consistency oracle etl

Tags: oracle, validation, testing, etl, consistency

I am new to oracle and I would like to know how do we check for misuse of integrity constraints and length of
datatypes as part of the ETL testing process. (The two tables could be T1 and T2). Please let me know a sample query.

Thanks, Santosh

Comment: you may use these queries in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746835/how-to-list-foreign-keys-referencing-a-primary-key/48747258#48747258 for T1 and T2 to detect primary-foreign key relations.

Answer (score 0):

If the referential integrity is set between two tables, the ETL tool should ideally make sure that the there is not any orphan record in the child table. You can check the same by executing similar query which should return zero records to pass the test.

```
SELECT fk   FROM dbo.ChildTable AS c  WHERE NOT EXISTS  (  SELECT pk FROM dbo.ParentTable AS p );
```

This should also be tested in the error log to check if any child records from the source is dropped because of failing referential integrity

In order to test the length of the datatypes the tester should make sure that the length of columns at the target DB is equal to or greater than the length of corresponding columns in the source database. For calculated fields the length should be equal to the maximum expected length of data. The QA should also check the data to make sure there is not any data truncation.